# How to fix scatter plot not sorting data on y - axis?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to graph these two sets of data I read from a csv file with pandas.  For some reason, the data always fits into a line and consequently the y axis gets messed up. How would I get this to graph correctly?

[image: Scatter Error]

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Paste and format the code instead. We're not going to re-type it... and the white hurts my eyes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is happening is that both your x and y variables are stored as strings, so the plot is showing you the string pairs in order. Try converting them to floats:

Example code:

```
arr0 = [float(x) for x in pred2[:,0]]
```

And do similarly for arr1 and it should plot as expected. Let me know if it works!